# Oracle SQL combine two columns into one without UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

In ORACLE 11G I have a SELECT with this kind of output:

```
COL_A       COL_B
-------     -------
BCS         (null)
(null)      FFG
VKD         FIU
...
```

I would like to get this:

```
MY_ALIAS
---------
BCS
FFG
VKD
FIU
...
```

COL_A and COL_B are columns from the same table. The query is a bit complex.

As you can see there are 3 types of row: COL_A with a value and COL_B  with null, the oposite and finally both columns with a value.

I know this can be done with a UNION this way:

```
SELECT MY_ALIAS FROM (
    
    SELECT (COL_A) AS MY_ALIAS
    WHERE <lots of conditions here>
        AND COL_A IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT (COL_B) AS MY_ALIAS
    WHERE <lots of conditions here>
        AND COL_B IS NOT NULL
)
```

But this way the conditions in WHERE clause would be exactly the same and I would like to avoid it.

**Is there any way to achieve that without duplicating ? Without PL/SQL, just a SELECT query**

*Edited to remove the need to avoid the UNION clause. The main purpose of my answer is to remove the duplication of .*

Thanks!

Comment: Move the `WHERE <lots of conditions here>` to outside the derived table. (Better code, much easier to maintain.)

Comment: I tried your solution and it works, thanks jarlh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You could try to use [UNPIVOT FUNCTION](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UNPIVOT)

```
SELECT 
   MY_ALIAS 
FROM 
(
    SELECT COL_A, COL_B AS MY_ALIAS
    WHERE <lots of conditions here>
) T UNPIVOT (MY_ALIAS FOR COL IN (COL_A, COL_B))
```

Comment: Coalesce is not working here because both columns could have a value (not null)

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstanded your question. I've edited my answer to use UNPIVOT function in ORACLE 11G.

Comment: It works. I dont know which is the best solution in terms of efficiency. This one seems pretty good as well.

Comment: For performance, you could reference this link http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12040.html. It's seem the UNPIVOT function will get better performance.

Comment: A very nice solution. (Remove `AS MY_ALIAS` from the subquery and add `DISTINCT` to the main query, though. And you don't have to make this even a main and a subquery anyway: `SELECT DISTINCT my_alias FROM mytable WHERE <lots of conditions here> UNPIVOT (my_alias FOR col IN (col_a, col_b))`).

Comment: I tried that last fine tuned one, Thorsten Kettner, and it works. I edited this answer to match your correction. Sorry but finally this seems to be the best answer, although its a combination of contributions.

Comment: @spekdrum: Don't worry; I consider this the best approach, too, and I certainly didn't have this brilliant idea to use `UNPIVOT` here.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `UNION ALL` first on all records with the desired column plus all columns you need in your where clause. Then get the distinct values.

```
select distinct mycol
from
(
  select col_a as mycol, col_a, col_b, col_c from mytable
  union all
  select col_b as mycol, col_a, col_b, col_c from mytable
) data
where <lots of conditions here>;
```

Comment: It works, but the key here is not the UNION ALL but it is the fact of moving <lots of conditions here> to the outer select in your example. Anyway I set this as the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `UNION ALL` kind of *is* the key here. You must make up rows with all columns you need in your where clause plus the `col_a` resp. `col_b`, so only `UNION ALL` makes sense. Only then can you apply the where clause and remove duplicates (with `DISTINCT`). So rather then `UNION ALL` + `DISTINCT` in one step (i.e. `UNION`), you separate the two processes. However, my other answer is better, anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WITH` clause to apply your criteria:

```
with filtered as
(
  select col_a, col_b from mytable where <lots of conditions here>
)
select col_a from filtered
union
select col_b from filtered;
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but it's a bit more verbose than putting the big where clause outside the UNIONs as jarlh and you answered before.

Comment: It's probably the best approach, though, because you only union records that you are actually interested in. (Imagine a table with one million of records and only ten rows that match your criteria. Would you want to glue 1 million rows to another 1 million rows and only then apply your criteria or simply union 10 plus ten rows?)

Comment: You are right! I changed the right asnwer to this. Thanks!